# How to get the date of a specific day in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a diferent number of days 
example (1=monday,2=tuesday.......)
and i need to return the date o this day in the current week

For example: if i send number 3 to my function, in this current week, today is sunday 23 , and i need that my function give me the date of the day 3 in this week, in this case the wednesday day was june-19 . 
other example i pass the number 5 to my function the function return me the date of   the day 5 this week (friday)= june-21 (2019/06/21)

something like that

```
let currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
```

Comment: What have you tried? *toISOString* gives you a UTC string, you probably don't want that. *getDate* gets the current day in the month, *getDay* gets you the current day in the week, and *setDay* sets it to a particular day in the week. That's all you need to do the job. ;-)

Comment: Yes but you understand what i need  ?

Comment: Yes, but SO is to help fix code you've written, not write it for you. You need something like `d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() + n)` where *d* is the current date and *n* is the day number you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy is fairly straight forward:

1. `new Date()` gets you the current date
2. The *getDay* method returns the day number of the date's day of the week
3. The *getDate* method returns the day number of the date's day of the month
4. The *setDate* method sets the day number of the date's day of the month

So you get the current date, subtract the current day number, then add the day number you want to the date. This will also wrap to previous and following months, e.g.

```js
/* Given a week day number, return the date for that
 * day in the current week.
 *
 * @param {number} dayNumber - number of day in week.
 *   If 0, returns Sunday at start of week
 *   If 7, returns Sunday at end of week
 *   Otherwise 1 Mon, 2 Tue, etc.
 *   If not an integer in range 0 to 7 returns undefined
 * @returns {number|undefined} date of supplied day number
 */
function getDateForDayInWeek(dayNumber) {
  dayNumber = Number(dayNumber);
  // Validate input
  if (dayNumber < 0 ||
      dayNumber > 7 ||
      parseInt(dayNumber) != dayNumber) {
    return; // undefined
  }
  let d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() + dayNumber);
  return d.getDate();
}

// Examples
console.log('Today is ' + 
  new Date().toLocaleString(undefined, {
    month:'long', weekday:'long', day:'numeric'
  })
);
// Sample values
[0,  // Sunday at start of week 
 3,  // Wednesday
 7,  // Sunday end of week
 23, -2, 2.4 // All invalid, return undefined
].forEach(
  n => console.log(n + ':' + getDateForDayInWeek(n))
);
```

You might want the function to return a Date, then you can do more with it, including just getting the date, but also the month and day name, etc.